# best all-in-one printer for the small office

Tags: printer, laser-printer

What should I look at when purchasing a printer? I've noticed that there are inkject and laser printers - what is the difference between them? Is there a general guideline in purchasing a particular type of printer?

Comment: It's not the right place, I'm afraid as the FAQ expressly forbids buying recommendations. Time to do a bit of Web searching for reviews and buyers guides. http://superuser.com/faq. PS: Having FAX facilities can be darn handy at times.

Comment: I thought it is a right place because little search for "recommend printer" on superuser gave quite few results. And it is hard to trust the reviews you find online these days, therefore that isn't really an option. To make the question more valid, I've added more details.

Comment: You can come to the chat and discuss (in case there are people around knowing their deal about printers). The thing about shopping recs is that they are very subjective, open-ended and localized. Editing your question won't really help, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried to make the question more like a guideline - but there have been questions similar to this - [Occasional text printing - inkjet or laser?](http://superuser.com/questions/252141/occasional-text-printing-inkjet-or-laser) , [Color Printer: Laser vs Inkjet](http://superuser.com/questions/130005/color-printer-laser-vs-inkjet). If you don't agree with the edits, you should be able to rollback

Answer (score 2):

Inkjet printers are a money pit if you do too much (ink cartridges are more expensive per page than toner) or too little (ink cartridges dry out after a month or two; toner is stable for years) printing.